# dhcrelay problem?

Tags: route, isc-dhcpd

dhcpd reply not getting to final client.

Background: 
 House network:

107.nn.164.89 - to internet

192.168.100.0/24 - house local lan1

192.168.1.254/30 - gateway to mancave

Mancave:

192.168.1.253/30 - gateway to house

192.168.200.254/24 - mancave local lan1

mancave dhcrelay sends requests to dhcp server running on house lan1 ( which also listens on 1.254/30 )

house dhcp does a reply to those requests.

I can see the reply coming in from the house on 1.253 and dhcrelay sends it to the 200.0/24 network; or so I think.

The 200.0/24 network show the request going out, nothing coming back in.

I can surf ( or whatever ) from the 200.0/24 network in the mancave if I manually set IP,Gateway ...etc.

dhcrelay, route, tcpdump follows:

darouter is house network

```
[root@darouter named]# tcpdump -i ens2 -nn port 67 or port 68
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
07:10:26.347170 IP 192.168.1.253.67 > 192.168.1.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548
07:10:26.347488 IP 192.168.1.254.67 > 192.168.200.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 310
07:10:34.427024 IP 192.168.1.253.67 > 192.168.1.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548
07:10:34.427282 IP 192.168.1.254.67 > 192.168.200.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 310
```

dacave is mancave network; first is 1.253/30 net

```
[root@dacave ~]# tcpdump -i enp3s0 -nn port 67 or port 68
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:09:45.827122 IP 192.168.1.253.67 > 192.168.1.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548
09:09:45.827647 IP 192.168.1.254.67 > 192.168.200.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 310
09:09:53.906938 IP 192.168.1.253.67 > 192.168.1.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548
09:09:53.907477 IP 192.168.1.254.67 > 192.168.200.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 310
^C
4 packets captured
```

200.0/24 net:

```
[root@dacave ~]# tcpdump -i enp5s0 -nn port 67 or port 68
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp5s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:09:45.827036 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548
09:09:53.906885 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548
^C
2 packets captured
```

dhcrelay config:

```
[root@dacave ~]# show dhc
206:  82462 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcrelay -d --no-pid 192.168.1.254 -i enp5s0
```

mancave route -n

```
[root@dacave ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.252   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp5s0
[root@dacave ~]#
```

house route -n

```
[root@darouter named]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         107.nn.164.89  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0f0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.253   0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens2
107.nn.164.88  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     100    0        0 enp2s0f0
192.168.1.252   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     100    0        0 ens2
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0f1
192.168.200.0   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ens2
[root@darouter named]#
```

As you can see, there are no replies coming back in on the 200.0/24 network.

Do I have a missing route or ?

Oh, firewall is wide open ( input,output and forward accept ). I have tried 'iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j SNAT to 192.168.1.253 and have removed the SNAT line all together.

Could NOT put dhcrelay in 'tags' - why in the world would someone need a 300 rep to do that?

icarus: tried -m forward in the dhcrelay startup - don't see a difference.
strace returns *pages* of stuff. I am not familiar with the command and --help is no help to me. Can I grep on something or set some command line switch to help?  I did notice during start up, the last message printed by dhcrelay is 'Dropped all Capabilities'. If you know, what does that mean?

Also, adding -v to the tcpdump line yields:

```
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:49:42.961047 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 576)
    192.168.1.253.67 > 192.168.1.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:e8:fb:00:67:37, length 548, hops 1, xid 0xdf341d5f, secs 3, Flags [none]
          Gateway-IP 192.168.200.254
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:e8:fb:00:67:37
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 548
            Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 192.168.200.101
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 4294967295
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 14: 
              Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server, Hostname
              Domain-Name, RP, TTL, BR
              MD, Router-Discovery, Static-Route, YD
              YS, NTP
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 23: "Linux 2.4.20-uc0 armv3l"
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 00:e8:fb:00:67:37
09:49:42.961603 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37859, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 338)
    192.168.1.254.67 > 192.168.200.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 310, hops 1, xid 0xdf341d5f, secs 3, Flags [none]
          Your-IP 192.168.200.10
          Gateway-IP 192.168.200.254
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:e8:fb:00:67:37
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Offer
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.1.254
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 86400
            Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
            Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 192.168.200.254
            Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 192.168.1.254
            Hostname Option 12, length 6: "UpEast"
            Domain-Name Option 15, length 14: "todhackett.com"
            BR Option 28, length 4: 255.255.255.255
            NTP Option 42, length 4: 192.168.1.254
^C
2 packets captured
```

if that helps.

Got it working. dhcrelay manual states that you set the port to listen for dhcp requests of which I did and left 1.252/30 out as only 2 IP's there. Ok so my sometimes shorted brain decided that there indeed are dhcp reply messages coming in so I set the 1.252/30 interface also in the line

```
dhcrelay -d --no-pid -i enp5s0 -i enp3s0 192.168.1.254
```

It all works great!  Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Is it possible to run a process tracer such as `strace` or `truss` on `dacave`? If so it would be interesting to confirm that the responses that you see going to 192.168.1.254 are getting to dhcrelay. Does adding `-m forward` to the `dhcrelay` help?

Comment: icarus: see my OP, add questions and other stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: Disclaimer, never used dhcrelay, usually avoid ISC stuff if I can, so I am not an expert, just doing debugging from first principles and trying to help. See if there is output of `strace -ttt -e select -p $PID` where $PID is the process id of dhcrelay at the time that tcpdump shows the replies coming from the server. If there are not too many lines then maybe add it to the question.

Comment: In the spirit of pushing buttons at random, can you try removing the `-i enp5s0`  option from dscrelay also, so it trys to figure out where to send the packets? If you are willing, can you say what OS and revision you are running on dacave?

Comment: Glad you got it working. My **guess** is that removing both the `-i enpXs0` values will also enable it to work.